# Dagger 2 can not resolve symbol 'DaggerAppComponent'

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I'm trying to create a simple app with retrofit 2, dagger 2 and MVP, but I struggle with dependencies, actualy, this is the error I get after i try to rebuild the project Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.StackOverflowError

and also in App class where I provide AppComponent:  can not resolve symbol 'DaggerAppComponent'

I'll try to show you what my project looks like so someone can see the problem, First one is my AppModule which includes PresentationModule.class

```
@Module(includes = PresentationModule.class)
public class AppModule {
    private App app;

    public AppModule(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public App provideApp() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

Presentation Module looks like this:

```
@Module(includes = InteractorModule.class)
public class PresentationModule {

    @Provides
    JokePresenter providePresenter(JokeInteractor jokeInteractor) {
        return new JokePresenterImpl(jokeInteractor);
    }
}
```

And InteractorModule:

```
@Module(includes = {NetworkModule.class, PresentationModule.class})
public class InteractorModule {

    @Provides
    JokeInteractor provideJokeInteractor(RetrofitService service, JokePresenter presenter) {
        return new JokeInteractorImpl(service, presenter);
    }
}
```

This is JokePresenter that has a reference to view and interactor:

```
public class JokePresenterImpl implements JokePresenter {

    private JokeView mJokeView;
    private List<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mJoke;
    private JokeInteractor jokeInteractor;

    public JokePresenterImpl(JokeInteractor jokeInteractor) {
        this.jokeInteractor = jokeInteractor;
    }

    @Override
    public void setView(JokeView view) {
        this.mJokeView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void getRandomJoke() {
        mJokeView.showProgress();
        jokeInteractor.getRandomJoke();
    }
}
```

And JokeInteractor that has a RetrofitService and JokePresenter references:

```
public class JokeInteractorImpl implements JokeInteractor {

    private RetrofitService retrofitService;
    private JokePresenter presenter;

    public JokeInteractorImpl(RetrofitService service, JokePresenter presenter) {
        this.retrofitService = service;
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    @Override
    public void getRandomJoke() {
        retrofitService.getRandomJoke()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<RandomJokeResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        presenter.onRandomJokeCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        presenter.onError(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(RandomJokeResponse randomJokeResponse) {
                        presenter.onNextRandomJoke(randomJokeResponse);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
  provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    //retrofit
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'

  //rx java
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

 //dagger2
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Can someone see the problem here?

Comment: Did you create a Component interface that handles the injection? If not, let me know and I am happy to provide an example.

Comment: You should show your gradle dependencies

Comment: Yes, I have a component interface that has AppModule, and methods where presenter is injected     void inject(App app);

    void inject(JokeActivity activity);

    void inject(JokeListActivity activity);

    void inject(JokeDialog dialog);

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I added my dependencies

Comment: Why do you have `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'` AND `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'` ?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/me/stats and this sample project: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel I hope they help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the implementation of:

```
@Module(includes = InteractorModule.class)
public class PresentationModule
```

and

```
@Module(includes = {NetworkModule.class, PresentationModule.class})
public class InteractorModule
```

You have a cyclic dependency. You need to rethink your design. I propose to decouple `Interactor` from `Presenter`.

A simple solution:

Change `getRandomJoke()` implementation to return `Observable` and subscribe to it inside `Presenter`. And remove `presenter` reference from `Interactor`.

Interactor:

```
public class JokeInteractorImpl implements JokeInteractor {

    private RetrofitService retrofitService;

    public JokeInteractorImpl(RetrofitService service) {
        this.retrofitService = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable getRandomJoke() {
        return retrofitService.getRandomJoke()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
@Override
public void getRandomJoke() {
    mJokeView.showProgress();
    jokeInteractor.getRandomJoke()
          .subscribe(new Observer<RandomJokeResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    onRandomJokeCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    onError(e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(RandomJokeResponse randomJokeResponse) {
                    onNextRandomJoke(randomJokeResponse);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution, it fixed my problem! Ty, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that dependencies added in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'
```

Comment: Not having annotation processor was the exactly problem I have. Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure adding `AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class` inside your modules.

Like this:

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
       ....//Other module classes
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me (Solution) :-**

***If you have any other build issues related to Dagger apart from DaggerAppComponent import issue, then make sure to fix them first, if not we will just end up wasting time.***

If you fix the other Dagger issues, & then build your project.
The DaggerAppComponent will get generated, & then all you have to do is import it.

**Brief info regarding the issue that I faced :-**

The mistake that I did was that, I had another Dagger build issue, but I ignored it & spent my time trying to fix 'DaggerAppComponent' import problem.

Wont be relevant to you but in my case, the DI module class annotated with @Module had a single abstract method, & hence the module class had to be made abstract as well. But later accidentally I added 2 other non-abstract methods within this same abstract class. So when I fixed this & re-build the project. DaggerAppComponent was available for import.

**This is all what I have in my app level build.gradle file in relation to dagger :-**

Within plugins block :

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Within dependencies block :

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.43.2"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.43.2"
```

(Please note that "2.43.2" was the latest available version at the time of posting this comment)

**My failed attempts (These answers didn't work for me) :-**

- Clean > Re-build > Invalidates caches & restart.
- Switching to Project view, deleting build folder & re-building the project.
- Trying out various dagger versions & extra dagger dependencies that I didnt require.